# What is the difference between xyz.client.routes.js and xyz.server.routes.js in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mean-stack, meanjs

I want to know when to use both the types of routing. 
I have a file called polls.client.routes.js with the following code:

```
'use strict';

//Setting up route
angular.module('polls').config(['$stateProvider',
  function($stateProvider) {
    // Polls state routing
    $stateProvider.
    state('listPolls', {
      url: '/polls',
      templateUrl: 'modules/polls/client/views/list-polls.client.view.html'
    }).
    state('createPoll', {
      url: '/polls/create',
      templateUrl: 'modules/polls/client/views/create-poll.client.view.html'
    }).
    state('viewPoll', {
      url: '/polls/:pollId',
      templateUrl: 'modules/polls/client/views/view-poll.client.view.html'
    }).
    state('editPoll', {
      url: '/polls/:pollId/edit',
      templateUrl: 'modules/polls/client/views/edit-poll.client.view.html'
    });
  }
]);
```

My polls.server.routes.js file has the following code:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function(app) {
  var users = require('../../../users/server/controllers/users.server.controller');
  var polls = require('../controllers/polls.server.controller');

  // Polls Routes
  app.route('/polls').get(polls.list);
  // app.route('/polls').post(users.requiresLogin, polls.create);

  app.route('/polls/:pollId').get(polls.read);
  // .put(users.requiresLogin, polls.hasAuthorization, polls.update)
  // .delete(users.requiresLogin, polls.hasAuthorization, polls.delete);

  // Finish by binding the Poll middleware
  app.param('pollId', polls.pollByID);
};
```

When I go to localhost:3000/polls it does not render the view (which should have happened considering the polls.clients.routes.js file) and instead, a JSON response is received with the data because the polls.list function in polls.server.controller.js directs this behavior:

```
exports.list = function(req, res) { 
  Poll.find().sort('-created').populate('user', 'displayName').exec(function(err, polls) {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(400).send({
        message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
      });
    } else {
      res.jsonp(polls);
    }
  });
};
```

I want the .html file to be rendered as is being directed in the polls.client.routes.js file. Please explain how this is to be done.

Answer (score 0):

Server.route.js is for the express route. Here you specify what node function should handle what incoming http request.

Client one is an angular route. Here you specify what view to load when user navigates to a particular url.